# How to know whether a journal is indexed by Thomson Reuters or Scopus?

Tags: publications, indexing

I am preparing to submit my first article to a specific journal. How can I know if a journal is indexed in Thomson Reuters or Scopus?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Scopus journal list:**

https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri

**Thomson Reuters Master Journal List:**

http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/mjl/

Comment: @ FuzzyLeapfrog, the journal that I am preparing to send to it, is present in both databases.

Comment: Well, then this journal is indexed in Thomson Reuters **and** Scopus. I wish you much success for your submission. @user137684

Comment: @ FuzzyLeapfrog, thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Simple, but useful!